# Javascript Jquery Internet Explorer 8 delay in rendering visual dom changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer-8, delay

currently I'm having a problem with my javascript in IE 8. I have two checkboxes, if I check one, the other one is unchecked. This works fine so far. In IE8 the visual change is only rendered, after I do a right click on that site for example.
Please see http://jsbin.com/usodik/9 for an example.
Anybody any hint to fix this?

Regards

Comment: Then why don't you use radio?

Comment: It's only a snippet. It has to be a checkbox :)

Comment: Nevermind, posting here gave me a fresh view. The problem is caused by using the onchange, which fires later in IE than in FF and Chrome. I'm thinking of just setting the event to onClick

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
function togglePrefixVisibility() {
    if (jQuery('#friendlyNames').is(':checked')){
        jQuery('#friendlyNames').attr('checked', false);
    }       
}

function toggleNameVisibility() {
    if (jQuery('#prefixes').is(':checked')){
        jQuery('#prefixes').attr('checked', false);
    }       
}
```

General guildelines:

- Always check/uncheck a checkbox with `.attr('checked', false)` or `.attr('checked', true)`. Don't use `attr('checked')` or `removeAttr()`, because attribute values reference to the ones set in html markup, not runtime.
- Always ask if a checkbox/radio is checked with `.is(":checked")` for the same reasons

**And also** use `onclick` instead of `onchange` in your checkboxes to call this functions.
I tested it and it's working fine.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Edgar, I had the code like this before. Problem is, that the attribute checked has the values [checked,undefined]. It's not a boolean. Is the use of .is() faster?

Comment: If you pass a boolean parameter, jquery takes in charge of switching the value of the attribute. You can see it in the jquery attr documentation.